# Numerical Partial Differentiation Check

Tags: finite-difference, numerics

In my computer vision course, we are working on extracting a 3D surface from a chain of 2D images taken under several conditions. This procedure is known as [Photometric stereo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometric_stereo). Prior to extracting the surface $f(x,y)$ numerically, we have to perform what's called a test of integrability :
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y\partial x}
\tag{1}$$
This sanity test can be tested numerically by discretizing the partial derivative so that it accepts small values (and thus we have to accept that to recover $f$, we recover it starting from small values). Numerically this translates to :
$$
\frac{\partial\displaystyle\left(\frac{\alpha(x,y)}{\gamma(x,y)}\right)}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial\displaystyle\left(\frac{\beta(x,y)}{\gamma(x,y)}\right)}{\partial x}\approx0
\tag{2}$$
where :
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\alpha(x,y)}{\gamma(x,y)}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\beta(x,y)}{\gamma(x,y)}
\tag{3}$$
essentially where $(\alpha(x,y),\beta(x,y),\gamma(x,y))$ are the coordinates of the measured value of the unit-normal vector at some point on the surface $f$.

> In short, how can we numerically check if $(2)$ is valid? what algorithm or procedure should we do to discretize the partial differentiation?

I am not familiar with advanced concepts such as discretizing partial differential equations. However, I am familiar with numerical integration techniques.

Comment: For me, it is not clear how $\alpha$ and the other functions are defined.

Comment: The answer depends on your tolerances. It is not too difficult to write something that is going to give you numbers (even the small ones), but you need to give more information. For example, if I could numerically (for now, assume magically) calculate the expression and tell you that the answer is 1e-8, is it acceptable? Also the functions, I assume, are sampled at discrete points. So there will be limits to how close they can be, is that correct?